# Should I use MethodInvoker or Action

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MethodInvoker vs Action for Control.BeginInvoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167771/methodinvoker-vs-action-for-control-begininvoke)

```
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
        {
            //get dataset from web service

            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { 
                //fill grid
            }));

            BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {
                //fill grid
            }));
        });
```

In C# 2.0 I was using allot the MethodInvoker to update the UI from a background thread, will it be wise to switch to Action when using under BeginInvoke? Is it faster or safer to use Action?

Comment: A similar question was already asked and answered here on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167771/methodinvoker-vs-action-for-control-begininvoke

Comment: I'm kind of baffled by the people suggesting that he use neither.  Are they using a different C# compiler than me?  Mine makes me pass something deriving from `System.Delegate`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253138/anonymous-method-in-invoke-call/253150#253150

Answer (score 2):

It really doesn't make a difference, as both are simply delegate types which take no parameters and don't return a value. However, in terms of naming semantics, `MethodInvoker` is specific to WinForms and should therefore be limited to that scope. `Action` is all-purpose and can be used in any area of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

They are both delegates, and identical to each other in definition (grabbed from MSDN):

```
public delegate void MethodInvoker()
public delegate void Action()
```

So at the IL level they should be pretty much identical. So I doubt it matters much which one you use. `Action` is more universal and more likely to be understood by more developers, but `MethodInvoker` does have a more descriptive name. Go with whichever one feels better to you.

But as davidsoa points out, you can skip them both and just use a lambda directly.