# Invoke ToolStripMenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, invoke, contextmenustrip

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to Invoke ToolStripMenuItem.

For example,I am calling a web service(ASynchrously) when result is returned.i populate drop down items according to result,(In call back method)

```
 ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripItemEx("start"));
```

but I get exception

**Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.**

**There is no invoke function associated with the toolstrip item**, 
 Is there another way I can do this? Am I trying to do this the completely wrong way? Any input would be helpful.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are trying to execute code that rely on control main thread in another thread, You should call it using `Invoke` method:

```
toolStrip.Invoke(() =>
{
    toolStrip.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripItemEx("start"));
});
```

When accessing controls members/methods from a thread that is different from thread that the control originally created on, you should use `control.Invoke` method, it will marshal the execution in the delegate of invoke to the main thread.

**Edit:** Since you are using `ToolStripMenuItem` not `ToolStrip`, the `ToolStripMenuItem` doesn't have `Invoke` member, so you can either use the form invoke by "`this.Invoke`" or your `toolStrip` its parent "`ToolStrip`" Invoke, so:

```
toolStrip.GetCurrentParent().Invoke(() =>
{
    toolStrip.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripItemEx("start"));
});
```

Comment: How to Invoke ToolStripMenuItem?THis control has no invoke method?

Comment: I guess he knows this ... he just can't find were to

Comment: Khan if you are using wpf you need to use `Dispatcher.Invoke`

Comment: Working with windows forms.Problem is ToolStripMenuItem has not Invoke method.Try your self.

Comment: @CKoenig I can't see any difference between the code you posted and mine: your code `toolStrip.Invoke(...)` andmy code `toolStrip.Invoke(() =>`

Comment: @Khan I Updated the answer check it.

Comment: It might be worth considering using the `MethodInvoker` delegate, as opposed to an Action (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167771/methodinvoker-vs-action-for-control-begininvoke)

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to access the menu item from a thread rather than the main thread, so try out this code:

```
MethodInvoker method = delegate
{
    toolStrip.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripItemEx("start"));
};

if (ToolStripMenu.InvokeRequired)
{
    BeginInvoke(method);
}
else
{
    method.Invoke();
}
```