# What this C# code mean?

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth

Can someone explain this to me.
I Have code like this, but I don't know what the meaning.

```
void ConnectionManager_ConnectionFailed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
    {
        if (cbAutoConnect.Checked)
            Connect();
        else
            State = ConnectState.NotFound;
    });
}
```

My question:

1. Is this method an EventHandler?
2. What the purpose of this code is?

   > BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
   >       {
3. What happened to the "State" when execution condition "Else"?

**Note:**

Connect is a Method.

State is an enum describe by this code

```
public ConnectState State
        {
            get
            {
                return _State;
            }

            {
                if (_State == value)
                    return;

                _State = value;

                switch (value)
                {
                    case ConnectState.Connected:
                        DoingSomeThing;
                        break;

                    case ConnectState.Connecting:
                        DoingSomeThing;
                        break;

                    case ConnectState.NotFound:
                        DoingSomeThing;
                        break;
                }

                if (StateChanged != null)
                    StateChanged(this, new EventArgs<ConnectState>(value));
            }
        }
```

**Another Hint**

The enum initiation

```
public enum ConnectState { Connected, Connecting, NotFound }
ConnectState _State = ConnectState.NotFound;
```

I do not know what this exactly, but I think this is a custom EventHandler declaration for "ConnectState" object/class.

```
public EventHandler<EventArgs<ConnectState>> StateChanged;
```

Comment: +1 for nice written question. Wish every new member will do so.

Comment: Its a eventhandler. For more details please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167771/methodinvoker-vs-action-for-control-begininvoke

Comment: @prashanth so `delegate()` is an pointer of method and `MethodInvoker` represents a delegate. Below @user3036342 said the `connect()` will repeat ass long the cbAutoConnect is chacked. Why this happen? I did not find a code for looping. IF anything to do with this code: `BeginInvoke` is like `Thread.Start()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this method an EventHandler?

Yes it is.

> What the purpose of this code is?

You are defining a anonymous method with `delegate { ... }` then casting it to [`MethodInvoker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) delegate and passing it to [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a06c0dc2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which is executing this anonymous method asynchronously on the thread that your control was created on.

> What happened to the "State" when execution condition "Else"?

If `cbAutoConnect.Checked` is `true`   `Connect` method is calling, otherwise `State's` value is changed to `ConnectState.NotFound`, that's it.

Comment: whether the `Connect ();` would be repeated during `cbAutoConnect` is checked, as a result of code `BeginInvoke ();` similar to `Thread.start()`, or caused by something else?

Answer (score 1):

It's an eventhanlder like you said. If the connection fails, and auto connect is checked, it tries to reconnect again, if not, it gives you a "NotFound" error by using the ConnectionState

I'd suggest asking your questions to the programmer who wrote this instead

Comment: I could not contact the programmer who wrote the code. so I tried to read the code for development purposes. Adds some minor features.

 
I still wonder, why the Connect (); continues to repetition. I did not find a code for looping. if anything to do with this code:

`BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() {`

Answer (score -2):

1 probably yes，also you can find who has  called  it to make sure the guess.
2 asyn excute the anonymous Delegate(method)
3 er~~ this member's  set method is very strange.

look this :  case ConnectState.NotFound:
                        DoingSomeThing;
after setting value , it is not over,  if the state is changed , go on DoingSomeThing.